# How to Keep Track of count-up timer and store time for later use

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to figure out if there is a better way than my approach to keep track and store a timer's result either second by second or every X amount of seconds so this data can be used again when the user goes back to the page again and pick up where it was left off.

My approach is to run a looped setTimeout() which runs a query using AJAX. I have it set to do it every 5 seconds and it works BUT I am concerned about the performance in the future with hundreds of users generating a query every 5 seconds almost simultaneously and I also don't like seeing the console getting filed with all these POST events since I don't know how users will interpret it.

Anyway, here's what my code looks like.

```
//This setTimeout() is not the loop. This only generates a 5 seconds delay between a previous action and the recurring update and it only performs the delay once. This is for a personal need.

setTimeout(function(){
    duration = getSeconds(); //this gets the current seconds listed on the timer
    console.log(duration);
    runUpdateProgress(c_id, id, 0, duration, 0, 1); //this passes the parameters to the function that does the update in the database
}, 5000);


//Here's the function that runs the setTimeout() loop and performs the update ever x seconds.

function runUpdateProgress(c_id, id, progress, duration, status, action){
    var func = setTimeout(function start() {
        //console.log({c_id, id, progress, duration, status, action});
        if(action == 1){
            duration = getStopWatchSeconds();
            updateSaveLessonProgress(c_id, id, progress, duration, status, action);
            setTimeout(start, 5000);
        }else{
            clearTimeout(func);
        }
    }, 5000);       
}
```

The code works, it updates the database and keeps the time stored and I can fetch the time that was last stored whenever I need it (maybe losing 5-8 seconds give or take but it's fine).

I'm just wondering if there is a better way to do this without hammering the database when there are a large amount of users triggering this query. I am not sure yet if this will actually affect the performance in the live environment but any better ideas are welcome.

Comment: "I also don't like seeing the console getting filed with all these POST events since I don't know how users will interpret it."...99.99% of your users will never open the console, so I wouldn't worry about that. And even if they did, they wouldn't have a clue whether what they were seeing was a problem or not. It's a developer tool. Regular users aren't interested in it and mostly don't even know it's there.

Comment: You're right to be concerned about performance though. over-frequent ajax polling can cripple a server when multiple users are doing is simultaneously, especially if the server environment can't scale dynamically. What's the use-case for this timer, exactly? Why do you need to feed the data to the server so frequently? Could you put it in localstorage (in case the user closes the page and later re-opens it) and then send to the server less frequently? Or maybe you'd be better using websockets, perhaps. It all depends on what the data is for and how critical it is.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the input. I thought of going the cookie way but I was afraid of the cookie expiration time and losing the data prior syncing with the DB. I did not think of localStorage as a solution and after looking into it, it turns out it's actually a good option for me. I'll have the details stored in localStorage every x seconds and then run a query every 60 to 120 seconds or even later. There is still the risk of an user clearing the localStorage but it's less likely to happen as with cookie expiring.